# "bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml" fails while Creating VM for instance 'concourse/0' from stemcell

Tags: concourse, cf-bosh

I am trying to spin up Concourse using "bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml".
I am using a VM with Ubuntu to setup Concourse. Below are the sytem details and the command output.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

4.4.0-101-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 18:29:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Command Output:bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml

Deployment manifest: '/root/concourse-lite.yml'
Deployment state: '/root/concourse-lite-state.json'

Started validating

Downloading release 'concourse'... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating release 'concourse'... Finished (00:00:03)
  Downloading release 'garden-runc'... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating release 'garden-runc'... Finished (00:00:03)
  Downloading release 'bosh-virtualbox-cpi'... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating release 'bosh-virtualbox-cpi'... Finished (00:00:03)
  Validating cpi release... Finished (00:00:00)
  Validating deployment manifest... Finished (00:00:00)
  Downloading stemcell... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating stemcell... Finished (00:00:03)
Finished validating (00:00:13)

Started installing CPI
  Compiling package 'golang-1.8-linux/c97f9a00c26b34a3f59ca15b0f5a079d7f7e27c334cc8100248143c5dc0d4c0a'... Finished (00:00:00)
  Compiling package 'golang-1.8-darwin/ee2bb46a25872469cd8fe0f4b0804bab5c39cc5512bbcc4335c8691a038d3e73'... Finished (00:00:00)
  Compiling package 'virtualbox_cpi/cb3116b9b6c2111a873bb4ea14a1f3544ccdd2af'... Finished (00:00:00)
  Installing packages... Finished (00:00:12)
 Rendering job templates... Finished (00:00:00)
  Installing job 'virtualbox_cpi'... Finished (00:00:00)
Finished installing CPI (00:00:12)

Starting registry... Finished (00:00:00)
Uploading stemcell 'bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent/3468.1'... Skipped [Stemcell already uploaded] (00:00:00)

Started deploying
  Creating VM for instance 'concourse/0' from stemcell 'sc-6196df8a-6e26-411f-70b5-0cc0466a5adf'... Failed (00:01:19)
Failed deploying (00:01:19)

Stopping registry... Finished (00:00:00)
Cleaning up rendered CPI jobs... Finished (00:00:00)

Deploying:
  Creating instance 'concourse/0':
    Creating VM:
      Creating vm with stemcell cid 'sc-6196df8a-6e26-411f-70b5-0cc0466a5adf':
        CPI 'create_vm' method responded with error: CmdError{"type":"Bosh::Clouds::CloudError","message":"Creating VM with agent ID '{{559adf3b-c06e-4af0-5564-6e86f5d95d81}}': Starting VM: Retried '30' times: Running command: 'VBoxManage startvm vm-e9498e46-c2ef-4772-69f0-627f95044b4a --type headless', stdout: 'Waiting for VM \"vm-e9498e46-c2ef-4772-69f0-627f95044b4a\" to power on...\n', stderr: 'VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'vm-e9498e46-c2ef-4772-69f0-627f95044b4a' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)\nVBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine\n': exit status 1","ok_to_retry":false}

Exit code 1

Comment: The first thing to do here is "google the error message". Typically the last bit is the most interesting: `Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine` ... go try that and I bet you'll find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with VirtualBox on your machine. Some folks running on Ubuntu have also reported seeing this same error [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1198060)